# 3D TABS with imrovments of width and height

Tags: html, css

I have a 3D Tab on my website which I got from codepen ([codepen.io/vavik96/pen/QjPVRL](http://codepen.io/vavik96/pen/QjPVRL)).

I increased the width (800px)  and height (550px).

No matter how much I tried I couldn't set a right size to it.

It should be screen web page sized to meet my needs.

Somebody help me.

Here my work.

```css
.perspective {
  -webkit-perspective: 76em;
  perspective: 76em;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 50px;
  width: 494px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

input { display: none; }

.tab {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 70px;
  background: pink;
  right: 0;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.tab:nth-child(1) {
  top: -80px;
  left:84px;
  background: #06D6A0;
}

.tab:nth-child(2) {
  top: -80px;
  left: 174px;
  background: #1B9AAA;
}

.tab:nth-child(3) {
  top: -80px;
  left: 262px;
  background: #EF476F;
}

.tab:nth-child(4) {
  top: -80px;
  left: 352px;
  background: red;
}

.cube {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100px;
  transform-origin: 100px 100px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
}

.tab-content {
  width: 800px;
  height: 550px;
  position: absolute;
}

.tab-content h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 75px 0 10px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.tab-content p { font-size: 12px; }



.tab-content:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
  transform: translateZ(700px);
  background:  #06D6A0;
}

.tab-content:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-270deg) translateY(-100px);
  transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  transform-origin: top left;
  background: #EF476F;
}

.tab-content:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(200px);
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateX(100px);
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
  -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  background: red;
}

.tab-content:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
  background: #1B9AAA;
}

#tab-one:checked ~ .cube {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}


#tab-two:checked ~ .cube {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}



#tab-three:checked ~ .cube {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

#tab-four:checked ~ .cube {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transform: rotateY(-270deg);
}
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="perspective">
  <label class="tab" for="tab-two">Tab 2</label>
  <label class="tab" for="tab-one">Tab 1</label>
  <label class="tab" for="tab-three">Tab 3</label>
  <label class="tab" for="tab-four">Tab 4</label>
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-one">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-two">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-three">
  <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab-four">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h1>Tab 1</h1>
      <p>THIS IS AWESOME</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h1>Tab 2</h1>
      <p>THIS IS COOL</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h1>Tab 3</h1>
      <p>THIS IS SWEET</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <h1>Tab 4</h1>
      <p>THIS IS Good JOB</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please include your code _here_. You can replace JSFiddle with a StackSnippet (ie runnable code within the question). The editor made you enter that formatted `?` for a reason - it wants to see the code _within the question_ - external links can disappear or change over time and ruin the integrity of the question for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 100% !important;
```

please add your code to your question next time you ask someone to help you.